# Passing IEnumerable property of model to controller post action- ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an asp-MVC application and facing the following issue:
Here is a working code:

```
<div id="detailsTemplates">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Filter.itemDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Filter.itemDetails[i].iD)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
```

Now in the post action in my controller I get the inserted value correctly.

Now, when I change the code to a partial view:

```
<div id="detailsTemplates">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Filter.itemDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("itemDetailsUserControl", Model.Filter.itemDetails[i]);
            }



        </div>
```

and the partial view looks like the following:

```
<div id="detailsTemplates">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.iD)
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Now the value is not transffered via the post.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of the model in the view is from the model being passed to it. 
E.g. by passing

```
Model.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i]
```

to your partial, you have changed the root from the Model object to your CustomiseDetails object. (so the name of the input will be "CustomsItemClassificationID" instead of "Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i].CustomsItemClassificationID", and so will not be rebound when posted, as will no longer match the property it is being bound to.

The correct way to do this is to use an **Editor Template**. This will preserve the model's origin. To do this, Create a folder called EditorTemplates under Views > Shared.

Copy your partial into it, and rename it to be called the name of your type. For example, if the type of  Model.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i] is CustomsitemDetail then your file under the editor template folder will be called CustomsitemDetails.cshtml.

Now, instead of

```
@Html.RenderPartial("CustomsItemDetailsUserControl", Model.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i]);
```

Use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails[i])
```

<del>Alternatively, if you don't want to rename or move your file, you can specify it's current location instead:</del>

<del>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails[i], "~/Views/{controller}/CustomsItemDetailsUserControl.cshtml")</del>

**UPDATE**

So I've learnt something new:

*If a template whose name matches the templateName parameter is found in the controller's EditorTemplates folder, that template is used to render the expression. If a template is not found in the controller's EditorTemplates folder, the Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder is searched for a template that matches the name of the templateName parameter. If no template is found, the default template is used.* from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414(v=vs.118).aspx).

So contrary to the second part of my answer, you do need to move your partial to

```
"~/Areas/TaxCalculation/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/CustomsItemDetailsUserControl.cshtml"
```

And use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails[i], "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl")
```

**UPDATE 2**

As per Stephen's comment - EditorFor() has an overload that accepts IEnumerable so  you can just use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails, "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl")
```

Or if you have an EditorTemplate named CustomitemDetails.cshtml located in the /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ folder:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails)
```

Comment: Thank you @Carl, upvoted.
I've replaced it with: 
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i], "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl");
and now it gets to the action with the correct value.
The problem is that using Editor FOR, I got all the properties as textboxes. What if i want to apply a dropdownlist for one property, textbox for the other and etc...How can I apply my own template for each item in the collection? I think it totally ignores my templates, cause my template includes only textbox for 1 property, and it displays all the properties of the corresponding object.

Comment: Hi DimaK, if you use my second example, and specify the path of your partial view as the second parameter (e.g. ~/views/{controller}/CustomsItemDetailsUserControl.cshtml), then the contents of the partial will be used as the editor template. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i], "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl");
@Carl, I used the second example, relative path, as I've noted in my first comment, and as I've mentioned it ignores it.

Comment: Hi DimaK, what you are posting (just "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl") is not the base-relative path - can you confirm you are using the tilde, followed by the full path? The liklihood is that the path is wrong, as MVC will first look for the specified file to create the editor, and if it cannot find it, will fall back to the default (normally a text box) - which is what it sounds like is happening in this instance.

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomsitemDetails[i], "~/Areas/TaxCalculation/Views/Home/CustomsItemDetailsUserControl.cshtml");  @Carl, still the same :(
and I can tell for sure the path is correct, cause if it is wrong, it displays cannot resolve view...

Comment: You do not need (and should not use) `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails[i], "CustomsItemDetailsUserControl")`. `EditorFor()` has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` so it should be just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filter.CustomitemDetails)` - no indexer!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the addition - I've added it to my answer

Comment: You actually don't need the `CustomsItemDetailsUserControl` parameter either so long as there is an `EditorTemplate` named `CustomitemDetails.cshtml` located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` folder

Comment: Thank you both. Going to change my code to the suggested solution.
@Carl can you please take a look at the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614669/transferring-info-from-view-to-controller