# Transferring info from view to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm working on an asp-mvc application and facing the following issue:
I have a model with simple properties plus one property which is a list of my custom object, and I render the Ienumerable property as mentioned here:
[Passing IEnumerable property of model to controller post action- ASP MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575192/passing-ienumerable-property-of-model-to-controller-post-action-asp-mvc/30575863#30575863)

In my view, I have a button that is supposed to add items to the ienumerable property of my model. Of Course, I don't want to lose already inserted data, so I need to pass the model to the corresponding action.

I've noticed that the model os transferred entirely only upon post. So, I did something like:

```
 $(".addButton").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#FilterForm").submit();
        @{ Session["fromAddFullItem"] = "true";}
        return false;
      });
```

And then in my controller, I do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(FilterModel model)
    {
        if (Session["fromAddFullItem"].ToString() == "true")
        {
            Session["fromAddFullItem"] = "false";
            return AddBlankItemTemplate(model);
        }
```

I've read that assigning session in js is not recommended, but also tried TempData, and there the data was always null.

My problem is that Session["fromAddFullItem"] is always true, even when I come from another button. If I put breakpoint in addbtn click in line- Session["fromAddFullItem"] = "false";, and press the other button, I see that for some odd reason the mentioned breakpoint is hit, even though I haven't pressed the add button.

Any help? Maybe there is another way to achieve what I want. Currently, no matter which button I press (which posts the form), it comes as Session["fromAddFullItem"] = "false" and goes to action AddBlankItemTemplate. Thanks.

EDIT - AJAX POST

```
    $(".addButton").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var modelData = JSON.stringify(window.Model);
        $.ajax({
            url:  '@Url.Action("AddBlankItemTemplate")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: modelData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        });
        return false;
    });
```

and controller

```
public ActionResult AddBlankItemTemplate(string modelData)
```

EDIT 2:

```
       $(".addButton").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddBlankItemTemplate")',
            data: $("#FilterForm").serialize()
        }).success(function(partialView) {

            $('DetailsTemplates').append(partialView);
        });
    });
```

and Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddBlankItemTemplate(FilterModel model)
```

Comment: `Session` is server code. You cant assign server value in client code.

Comment: Answer given below is correct. But I want to know what are you trying to achieve by setting that session value? What is your objective?

Comment: StephenMuecke any suggestions how can i achieve what I want?
I even tried AJAX post, and transferring the model directly to AddBlankItemTemplate, but model was always undefined, I guess the model is also server side. @shwetaOnStack I just want to go to action AddBlankItemTemplate with my whole model (all the inserted input).

Comment: Ajax post must work if you are passing model correctly or you can use Ajax.BeginForm. Please post your code for AJAX call in your question above. How are you passing the model in that call?

Comment: @shwetaOnStack question edited with my AJAX post, modeldata in controller is null

Comment: @DimaK. Its a little unclear what you are actually trying to do. Do you want to post your model and include and additional value (`true/false`)? In which case, why not use a view model that includes an additional `boolean` value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if model is passed correctly to my action- AddBlankItemTemplate, then I don't need the boolean value. So basically, if I go with AJAX solution, I just need to figure out how to pass my model entirely to my action in controller.

Comment: It unclear why you even need ajax (you don't do anything in the success callback so why not a normal submit?), but it just needs to be `$.post('@Url.Action("AddBlankItemTemplate")', $('form').serialize(), function(data) { ...}` and then in the controller `public ActionResult AddBlankItemTemplate(YourModel model)`

Answer (score 2):

The line `@{ Session["fromAddFullItem"] = "true";}` is Razor code and will be run on page rendering and load regardless of where you put it in the page.

It's not client side code so won't wait for your js code to run. If you're trying to synchronise state between js and MVC have you looked into angularjs which could simplify these actions.